# How to calculate the basic sum of two numbers using nodejs restAPI through Postman

Tags: node.js, api, postman, node-modules, rest

Following is my server.js file code,

```
var express = require('express');
console.log("A");
var app = express();
console.log("b");
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("c");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
    var f = parseInt(req.body.a);
    console.log(req.body.a);
   var l = parseInt(req.body.b);
    var sum = Number(f + l);
    res.send('The sum is: ' + Number(sum));

})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

When I provide the values of `f` and `l` using the postman following the url `http://localhost:8081/listUsers`,

The output I am getting is `The sum is: NaN`

Can you tell me why ? Am I missing something ??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following as you are not receiving req body json

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // add this line
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added a given line `app.use(bodyParser.json());` but yet it's showing NaN and in console, it;s showing `undefined`. Can you please tell what's wrong I did here ?

Comment: Have you selected following correct options under body section in postman
raw > JSON in dropdown. 
Also you should use post method if you are passing params.
Send me screenshot if still getting errors

Comment: or you can also use x-www-form-urlencoded in postman under Body.